# HorizontalChildrenAlignment="Stretch" is not working in WrapGrid

Tags: gridview, alignment, uwp

```
<GridView ItemsSource="{Binding SomeSource}" >
    <GridView.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <WrapGrid Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalChildrenAlignment="Stretch"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </GridView.ItemsPanel>
    <GridView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <ContentControl>
                   <!--hidden for simplicity-->
                </ContentControl>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </GridView.ItemTemplate>
</GridView>
```

`HorizontalChildrenAlignment="Stretch"` in WrapGrid has no effect? How can I make the grid items to align in such a way that the leftmost items will keep to the left border of the WrapGrid, while the rightmost items will keep to the right border of the WrapGrid, and extra space distributed evenly in between the grid items?

Currently, the space between the grid items is the specified margin in grid items, and there is a large gap between the rightmost items to the right border of the WrapGrid, if the remaining space is not sufficient to fit in another grid item. Ideally, we want the extra space to be distributed evenly in between grid items, instead of leaving a left-over space at the right of the rightmost grid items.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is this?

```
<WrapGrid  Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalChildrenAlignment="Stretch"/>
```

not horizontal but `VerticalChildrenAlignment`. I have to add, it does look strange if there's not at least one wrapped item, since resizing  horizontally will make the items "jump"

Comment: This is the exact behavior I am looking for. Awesome.

Comment: Hello. Could you please give a little more info on the matter? With provided XAML code the items and the spaces between them grow larger as the total space increases. Is it possible to somehow tune WrapGrid so it would resize elements to fill the horiazontal space (not create/enlarge spaces between the items)?

Answer (score 0):

[WrapGrid](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.wrapgrid) doesn't have this kind of a dynamic functionality out-of-the box. If you have a fixed amount of items to show, you can calculate the optimal margin manually.

Other option is to switch from GridView to Grid and [adapt the WPF code shown here.](http://blog.scottlogic.com/2010/11/15/using-a-grid-as-the-panel-for-an-itemscontrol.html) But that isn't completely dynamic solution either as you need to define how many items is shown on each row.